# Jinja2 - split string

Tags: jinja2

I am trying to split out a shopping list string that looks like the following:

```
['Milk', 'Bread', 'sugar', 'rinse aid']
```

The string has 4 shopping list items, whereby I want to remove the [] at the front and the end, remove the '', and separate each item on a separate line if possible.

Comment: Sorry to add, the string may have 1 to many items, not just 4 as per the example :)

Answer (score 1):

Your shopping list is not a `string`, its a `list`.

You can use [for loop](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#for) to iterate through each item and print it separately,

```
{% set shoppinglist = ['Milk', 'Bread', 'sugar', 'rinse aid'] %}

{%- for item in shoppinglist -%}
  {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Output,**

```
Milk
Bread
sugar
rinse·aid
```

You can [test it here](http://jinja.quantprogramming.com/)

Comment: Thanks very much for the response! The next question I have is I want this to take the shoppinglist value from an attribute in Home Assistant. The variable's name is sensor.shopping_list and has the values of the list. Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

First I will presume that what you have is a list of items which you would like to show in a web page-

```
app.route('/myList')
def myList():
    list=['Milk', 'Bread', 'sugar', 'Colagate']
    return render_template('shoppingList.html',slist=list)
```

and in the shoppingList.html

```
{% for x in slist %}
 <div class="someClass">{{ x }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

this should work for a list

If you have a string that looks like-

```
 listStr="['Milk', 'Bread', 'sugar', 'Colagate']"
```

what you can do is define-

```
 def listMaker(lst):
    listStr=listStr.replace(']','')
    listStr=listStr.replace('[','')
    listStr=listStr.replace(',','')
    listStr=listStr.replace('\'','')

    list=listStr.split(' ')
    return list
```

and then call this function-

```
app.route('/myList')
def myList():
    listStr="['Milk', 'Bread', 'sugar', 'Colagate']"
    list=listMaker(listStr)
    return render_template('shoppingList.html',slist=list)
```

the HTML code remains the same.